# Is it a good idea to delete yarn.lock and generate it again by running yarn install?

Tags: yarnpkg

Recently I installed several npm packages, which I then have to remove. Now I'm not sure about the **yarn.lock** file and think it might have some legacy code inside it.

Is it a good idea to delete **yarn.lock** and generate it again by running yarn install?

Comment: No need to delete the file, just run `yarn` and it'll update all dependencies.

Comment: Voted to reopen as it seems sufficiently different from the 'duplicate'.

Comment: Agreed @stevec, by title alone, this appears quite different

Comment: But the question still remains. Is it a good idea or not to delete the yarn.lock? Would a regeneration of the yarn.lock produce an identical result from yarn upgrade?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yarn.lock is a generated file yarn uses to know what versions of each dependency are installed so it can get those exact versions again when you run yarn install on a new machine. You don't need to delete it to remove the packages you aren't using any more from it, just remove them from package.json and run yarn upgrade and it will uninstall those packages and generate a new lock file without them

Comment: I think you mean `yarn upgrade` (there is no `yarn update` command)? It's so confusing switching between npm and yarn!

Comment: @ninjaPixel You are correct! Thanks for catching that, updated the answer

Comment: You should note that doing ```yarn upgrade``` will look at all your dependencies and upgrade any that have newer versions in the npm registry. This implies you might want to test thoroughly after doing so to make sure your application still works.

Comment: @LeeMeador huh yes you are correct now that you mention it, does running yarn or yarn install (I can't remember which is correct) remove items no longer in package.json without upgrading? I kind of assumed upgrade would be the way to go since install reads from the lock file

Comment: still not clear, if i delete the old yarn.lock and regenerate, and install in old and new machines, aren't they still use the exact same version of packages ?

The reason i'm asking is, i see different final yarn.lock when delete or not delete the old yarn.lock

Comment: @user3552178 yarn.lock exists to lock the packages you installed to an exact version. If you run yarn on a directory with yarn.lock in it then it should install the same dependencies on every machine of the same platform. Native dependencies can vary between platforms, so those aren't guaranteed the same on every machine, but everything else should. If there is no yarn.lock yarn installs the latest version of all packages, within the constraints of your package.json file.